# Magento 2: reindexing is not working

Tags: magento, magento2

I'm not able to do **reindexing** in **magento 2**. After google I get the solution that We can reindex with shell command

```
php dev/shell/indexer.php reindexall
```

But it's giving error

```
Could not open input file: dev/shell/indexer.php
```

As I can't see **shell** folder within **dev**.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Stack Overflow is a programming-related Q&A site. Your question is not about programming. Perhaps you should post it on http://magento.stackexchange.com/ instead?

Comment: @Enigmativity, It's a programming question as indexing is not working with magento 2

Comment: Unless you're replacing the indexing with one you're writing then this is a server management exercise.

Comment: @Enigmativity, please check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19518136/magento-reindexing-data-risks

Comment: That question is off-topic too. See [Questions on professional server, networking, or related infrastructure administration are off-topic for Stack Overflow unless they directly involve programming or programming tools](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Answer (score 16, accepted):

**fire this command from magento root via terminal**

reindex all :  **php bin/magento indexer:reindex**

reindex perticuler : **php bin/magento indexer:reindex indexer_name**

Where **indexer_name** Should be
catalog_category_product,catalog_product_category,catalog_product_price,catalog_product_attribute,cataloginventory_stock,catalogrule_rule,catalogrule_product,catalogsearch_fulltext.

Answer (score 6):

In your root magento directory type this:

**php bin/magento indexer:reindex**

This will perform a full reindex. If you wish to reindex only one of the indexers, command is as follows:

**php bin/magento indexer:reindex indexer_name**

where indexer_name can be found by typing:

**php bin/magento indexer:info**

Comment: Can't we do it via magento admin?

Comment: In Magento 2, I didn't find any option to re-index through admin.

Answer (score 2):

Using command prompt,

go to your Magento root directory.

```
cd your_magento_directory
```

Then run following command

```
php bin/magento indexer:reindex
```

If you want to do reindex specifically, then your comment will be:

```
php bin/magento indexer:reindex [indexer]
```

Answer (score 1):

This works for me.

You can manually run reindex. Go to your magento bin folder in root of magento install folder and run:
$ php magento indexer:reindex

Reference: http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/config-guide/cli/config-cli-subcommands-index.html

The better way is to config cronjob. follow the guide here: http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/config-guide/cli/config-cli-subcommands-cron.html#config-cli-cron-bkg

Magento2 is designed to not have manually reindex in admin. Refer to: https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/824

Answer (score 1):

http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/comp-mgr/prereq/prereq_compman-ulimit.html
Set ulimit for the web server user

To optionally set the value in the user’s Bash shell:

If you haven’t done so already, switch to the Magento file system owner.
Open /home//.bashrc in a text editor.
Add the following line:

ulimit -s 65536
Save your changes to .bashrc and exit the text editor.

Comment: I'm not sure..what you are talking about

Answer (score 0):

In magento2 they don't have an indexer.php under shell directory.
If you run `magento cron:run` twice it will rebuild the indexes.

Command line interface

[Reindex CLI](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/config-guide/cli/config-cli-subcommands-index.html)

Answer (score 0):

That's correct. To keep indexers up-to-date, run cron as the [Magento file system owner](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/install-gde/prereq/apache-user.html).

One way is to set up a crontab for that user:

```
*/1 * * * * php <your Magento install dir>/bin/magento cron:run &
```

Details: http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/config-guide/cli/config-cli-subcommands-cron.html

Answer (score 0):

```
shell folder are reside under dev directory of magento2 root.
Open your cmd.
go to magento bin directory path using CLI.
Your path like C:\wamp\www\magento2\bin.(if wamp is installed on C directory)
Now You have to enter command php magento indexer:reindex
All indexing are successfully reindex.
```

You can look more info in magento core document link: http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/config-guide/cli/config-cli-subcommands-index.html

Answer (score 0):

If you using xampp on Linux, CLI command would be

```
/opt/lampp/bin/php bin/magento indexer:reindex
```

Answer (score 0):

For windows system you have to follow the below steps :

step:1 Create environment variable as

```
Go to My Computer -> Right Click -> Properties -> Advanced System Settings -> Advanced -> Environment Variable -> System Variable -> Path -> Edit -> Enter you xampp->php path (Example : E:\xampp\php).
```

Step:2 Open CMD and run the below command on the root folder of your Magento project

```
php bin/magento indexer:reindex
```