# How we can reindex magento indexes in magento 2.0

Tags: magento2

I'm want  to do reindexing in magento 2. We can reindex with terminal command?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Magento 2: reindexing is not working](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33479082/magento-2-reindexing-is-not-working)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Magento 2: reindexing is not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33479082/magento-2-reindexing-is-not-working/34081669#34081669)

fire this command from magento root via terminal

to reindex all :

```
php bin/magento indexer:reindex
```

**OR**

reindex perticuler :

```
php bin/magento indexer:reindex indexer_name
```

Where indexer_name Should be from followings:

- catalog_category_product
- catalog_product_category
- catalog_product_price
- catalog_product_attribute
- cataloginventory_stock
- catalogrule_rule
- catalogrule_product
- catalogsearch_fulltext

Comment: either 1 or 2 . one is working on beta version and another is working on stable version .

Comment: Thanks. This is nice artical

Answer (score 0):

**Get list of available indexing in Magento 2**

> magento indexer:info

**Check indexing status**

> magento indexer:status

Even you can check individual indexing status using below command

> magento indexer:status catalog_category_product

**How to reindex all available indexing in Magento 2**

> magento indexer:reindex

**In case you fill memory limit, try this command**

> php -dmemory_limit=2G magento indexer:reindex